# Using Linq to read database table

Tags: c#, linq

I have an issue that I am trying to resolve where I have a relationship between two tables.  As soon as I save a record to the 1st Table I then want to read that same record back so I can get the primary key and assign it to my next table.

Code I have written is below

```
public IEnumerable<CombinedPayCode> ImportCombinedPayCodes()
{
    var xmlFile = Path.Combine(_xmlPath, "WSACombinedPayCodeRule.xml");
    var stream = new FileStream(xmlFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    var combinedPayCodeCollection = xdoc.Descendants("WSACombinedPayCodeRule");
    var Collection = new List<CombinedPayCode>();
    foreach (var element in combinedPayCodeCollection)
    {
        var combinedPayCode = new CombinedPayCode
        {
            Name = (string)element.Attribute("Name"),
            AmountType = (string)element.Attribute("AmountType"),
            VisibleInReport = (bool)element.Attribute("VisibleInReport"),
            MoneyCategory = (bool)element.Attribute("MoneyCategory"),
            VisibleToUser = (bool)element.Attribute("VisibleToUser"),
            CustomerId = 11,
        };
        _db.CombinedPayCodes.Add(combinedPayCode);

        // I want to obtain the Primary Key of the above record once saved to database

        var payCodeNodes = element.Descendants("SimpleValue");
        foreach (var selectedPayCode in payCodeNodes)
        {
            var combinedPayCodeList = new CombinedPayCodeList
            {
                PayCodeId = selectedPayCode.FirstAttribute.Value,

                // I want to replace the next line of code to assign the 
                // foreign key as per the primary key of the record above

                CombinedPayCodeId = 1,
            };
            _db.CombinedPayCodeLists.Add(combinedPayCodeList);
        }
        _db.SaveChanges();

        Collection.Add(combinedPayCode);
    }

    return Collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the primary key of `CombinedPayCode` an identity column? If so, just reference `combinedPayCode.ThePrimaryKeyColumn` in your code.

If `CombinedPayCodeList` is a collection of something that hangs off `CombinedPayCode` you can save yourself some effort and just build the object graph and add the parent object then SubmitChanges(). EF will take care of transferring the primary key into the child entity and wrap everything in a nice neat transaction for you.

UPDATE: Something like this. I may have some of your object/property names wrong.

```
foreach( var element in combinedPayCodeCollection )
{
    // Create the CombinedPayCode object

    var combinedPayCode = new CombinedPayCode
    {
        Name = (string)element.Attribute("Name"),
        AmountType = (string)element.Attribute("AmountType"),
        VisibleInReport = (bool)element.Attribute("VisibleInReport"),
        MoneyCategory = (bool)element.Attribute("MoneyCategory"),
        VisibleToUser = (bool)element.Attribute("VisibleToUser"),
        CustomerId = 11,
    };

    var payCodeNodes = element.Descendants("SimpleValue");

    foreach( var selectedPayCode in payCodeNodes )
    {
        var combinedPayCodeList = new CombinedPayCodeList
        {
            PayCodeId = selectedPayCode.FirstAttribute.Value,
        };

        // Add each PayCodeNode to the CombinedPayCode
        combinedPayCode.CombinedPayCodeLists.Add( combinedPayCodeList );
    }

    // Add the CombinedPayCode (which includes all the PayCodeNodes) to
    // the object context and save the whole shebang.

    _db.CombinedPayCodes.Add(combinedPayCode);
    _db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You will have to forgive me I am a relatively new developer in C#.  The primary key of CombinedPayCode is an identity column but it is autoassigned int when save to the database, so combinedPayCode never actually contains the primary key.  The CombinedPayCodeList is a collection of something that hangs off CombinedPayCode, but I am not sure what you mean by "build the object graph and add the parent object then submit changes.  Can you elaborate for me

Comment: Actually ignore last comment.  I think I worked out what you were suggesting.  I added a collection to my CombinedPayCode Model for CombinedPayCodeList and then added it to the constructor, then I add the record to the constructor.  Anyway it worked.  thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess that you are using Entity Framework based off the syntax.

You can do this:

```
_db.CombinedPayCodes.Add(combinedPayCode);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Then `combinedPayCode.Id` should have it's primary key.  This not the best way to do it if you need that ID as a Foreign key on another table.  Then you would do:

```
combinedPayCode.CombinedPayCodeLists.Add(combinedPayCodeList);
_db.CombinedPayCodes.Add(combinedPayCode);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

In this case you only have to save one time, and it wraps all the db changes in a transaction.  If one fails, they all fail.

Hope this helps!